# How much control do G Suite admins have over my computer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace

My employer has provided me with a G Suite account. For convenience purposes, I like to stay signed in to it in Chrome.

I was wondering, **how much control does my G Suite admin have over my G Suite account and computer?**

Can they see my browsing activity? (normal and Incognito)
Can they see what files I have on my PC?
Can they download/edit files to my PC?
Can they add Chrome extensions to my PC?

Can they see my search history?
Can they see what Google Docs I've opened?
Can they see what other accounts I'm signed into Chrome with?

Note: For the purposes of the question, I am using my personal computer, owned and bought by myself, set up by myself, running Windows 10 Home.

The only way my computer is related to my employer is that I'm signed into Chrome with it ( for Sync purposes), and that I'm signed into Docs with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your G Suite admin cannot spy on your activity on the computer, but can trace
any aspect of the work that you do with G Suite apps.

That is, unless he has added some nasty add-ons to G Suite.

See
[Google to Allow Employers to Track Their Staff Using G Suite](https://www.maketecheasier.com/google-employers-track-g-suite/).

Comment: I've discovered something called [Chrome Management](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188446?hl=en&ref_topic=4386754), that might let my employer spy on me, but I don't see any extensions installed, and there doesn't appear to be any way to hide them.

Comment: Also, can he download or edit files on my PC?

Comment: What does "nasty add-ons" mean?

Comment: If your computer came from your employer, there is no limit to what he can do with additional installed programs. Your choices are either to trust his lack of interest in your personal life, or not to use his computer for practices he wouldn't like.

Comment: As stated above, the computer is owned by me.

Comment: Then I stand by my answer. If G Suite was downloaded from Google, then it certainly doesn't contain any illegal spy software. If the installation came from your employer and he is a respectable company, then he wouldn't use illegal means.

Comment: How do you download G Suite? G Suite is web-based. There shouldn't be anything to download. (At least, nobody's told me about it.)

Comment: Sorry, wrong verb (and product). Standard G Suite doesn't have spying tools. There do exist commercial spy tools such as [this one](https://www.ez-admintools.com/), but the most they can do is read your Gmail, which a normal G Suite admin cannot do without taking ownership of your account. If you wish to know what the admin can normally do, see for example [Account activity reports](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580176). In any case, good practice is never using the company Gmail for private messages, because they can and may be used against you.

Comment: So he cannot monitor my browsing activity without me knowing, or download files to my PC?

Comment: Yes, this is no part of G Suite. He can on only admin G Suite, not the entire browser, and is limited to legal actions that wouldn't get Google into legal problems.